# Silent install (powershell)

Tags: powershell

I use powershell for remote installation. The installation is performed using commands.

```
*$command = “cmd.exe /c C:\program\program.exe /SILENT”
$process = [WMICLASS]“\ROOT\CIMV2:win32_process“
$process.Create($command)*
```

After show Window **User Account Control**

Can you advise me on how PowerShell can disable the display box below so that the installation is carried out automatically?

Comment: Is Powershell running from an elevated command prompt?  You said that this was for remote installation, yet this looks like you are running it locally.  How are you doing it remotely?  Are you using Invoke-Command?

Comment: Meanwhile commands I test on localhost. How can I Run the command with administrator rights ? I will be very happy to if you help me, because I am a beginner

Comment: Take a look at the documentation of Invoke-Command, specifically Example #15.  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

Comment: as an aside ... your post shows curled/slanted quotes. those are known to cause odd problems in that they are _sometimes_ not recognized as quotes, _sometimes_ seen as illegal characters, and other times they work just fine. [*sigh ...*] /////  you are **_strongly_** recommended to never, ever use such in powershell code since they are very difficult to notice in advance of a glitch ... and sometimes difficult to notice after a glitch.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on your PowerShell shortcut and choose 'Run as administrator', this should circumvent UAC windows from popping up when an administrator action is executed inside your PowerShell session

[image]

Alternatively, see this post on exlcuding specific applications from windows UAC:
http://lifehacker.com/how-to-eliminate-uac-prompts-for-specific-applications-493128966